# SQL to find max of sum of data in one table, with extra columns

Tags: sql, sum, max, apache-drill

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere. I have been looking on Stackoverflow all day and haven't found an answer yet. I am struggling to write the query to find the highest month's sales for each state from this example data.

The data looks like this:

```
| order_id  | month  | cust_id  | state  | prod_id  | order_total  |
+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------------+
| 67212     | June   | 10001    | ca     | 909      | 13           |
| 69090     | June   | 10011    | fl     | 44       | 76           |
... etc ...
```

My query

```
SELECT `month`, `state`, SUM(order_total) AS sales 
FROM orders GROUP BY `month`, `state` 
ORDER BY sales;

|   month    | state  | sales  |
+------------+--------+--------+
| September  | wy     | 435    |
| January    | wy     | 631    |
... etc ...
```

returns a few hundred rows: the sum of sales for each month for each state. I want it to only return the month with the highest sum of sales, but for each state. It might be a different month for different states.

This query

```
SELECT `state`, MAX(order_sum) as topmonth
FROM (SELECT `state`, SUM(order_total) order_sum FROM orders GROUP BY `month`,`state`) 
GROUP BY `state`;

| state  | topmonth  |
+--------+-----------+
| ca     | 119586    |
| ga     | 30140     |
```

returns the correct number of rows with the correct data. BUT I would also like the query to give me the month column. Whatever I try with GROUP BY, I cannot find a way to limit the results to one record per state. I have tried PartitionBy without success, and have also tried unsuccessfully to do a join.

TL;DR: one query gives me the correct columns but too many rows; the other query gives me the correct number of rows (and the correct data) but insufficient columns.

Any suggestions to make this work would be most gratefully received.

I am using Apache Drill, which is apparently ANSI-SQL compliant. Hopefully that doesn't make much difference - I am assuming that the solution would be similar across all SQL engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick

```
SELECT  t1.`month`, t1.`state`, t1.`sales`
FROM    (
            /* this one selects month, state and sales*/
            SELECT  `month`, `state`, SUM(order_total) AS sales 
            FROM    orders
            GROUP BY `month`, `state` 
        ) AS t1
JOIN    (
            /* this one selects the best value for each state */
            SELECT  `state`, MAX(sales) AS best_month
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  `month`, `state`, SUM(order_total) AS sales 
                        FROM    orders
                        GROUP BY `month`, `state` 
                    )
            GROUP BY `state`
        ) AS t2
ON      t1.`state` = t2.`state` AND
        t1.`sales` = t2.`best_month`
```

It's basically the combination of the two queries you wrote.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, this works, and does what I need. I had a feeling it would be a join.

Comment: @JustinWatkins go ahead and mark Stefano's answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT `month`, `state`, SUM(order_total) FROM orders WHERE `month` IN
  ( SELECT TOP 1 t.month  FROM ( SELECT  `month` AS month,  SUM(order_total) order_sum FROM orders GROUP BY `month`
ORDER BY  order_sum DESC) t) 
GROUP BY   `month`, state ;
```

Comment: Thanks Abdullah. It appears that TOP isn't supported in Apache Drill, and this query fails with an error at that point. Is TOP in the ANSI standard?